# Bremsstrahlung (or pair production) with polarized electrons

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization, pair-production

I am looking for a good reference for bremsstrahlung on polarized electrons in Born approximation (theory-wise). I found articles like [McVoy](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.106.828), where they exactly talk about what I need... But I can't reproduce their results (eqn. 7), even the powers of momenta don't make sense to me. Also, they work in different notations, from the ones the most of modern textbooks use.

In the books I found Bethe-Heitler formula for non-polarized case only. I know in principle what to do, but if I work it out myself, I get results, different from the ones in the papers.

If you know a good reference, please, help.